# For loop should add entries to dictionary but only keeps one

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, data-structures

This is my very first question here, i've done the research but couldn't really find something similar.

Main goal of my script when it's done:
I want it to scan all the lines within a text file against a regular expression. If there is a match, the current line and an incremental index shall be added to a dicionary. At EOF the now filled dictionary shall be written into a new file.

Current problem: 
When running the for loop for scanning the lines the dictionary never seems to get more than one entry despite the scanner actually finding multiple matches (confirmed by simple print statement when match is true. What did I miss?

```
for inputfile in inputfiles:
print("Processing "+ inputfile)

inputfile = os.path.join(filespath,inputfile)

with open (inputfile, "r", encoding="UTF-8") as infile:
    alllines = infile.readlines()

matched_lines = {}
int_index = 1
indexer = str(int_index).zfill(5)
for line in alllines:
    if re.search(match_string,line,flags=0):
        matched_lines[indexer] = line
        int_index += 1
print (matched_lines.items())
```

This is what it outputs:
Processing Testfile 1.txt
dict_items([('00001', 'Zeile 5\n')])

But this "Zeile 5\n" (the regex match is 5$) is multiple times within the text file it is scanning. The said file just looks like this:

```
Zeile 3
Zeile 4
Zeile 5

Zeile 1
Zeile 2
Zeile 3
Zeile 4
Zeile 5

Zeile 1
Zeile 2
Zeile 3
Zeile 4
Zeile 5

Zeile 1
Zeile 2
Zeile 3
Zeile 4
Zeile 5

Zeile 1
Zeile 2
Zeile 3
```

etc

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never updating the indexer after the first iteration, look:

```
int_index = 1
indexer = str(int_index).zfill(5)

for line in alllines:
    if re.search(match_string,line,flags=0):
        matched_lines[indexer] = line # indexer was always the same!
        int_index += 1
        indexer = str(int_index).zfill(5) # this should fix it
```

Comment: Oh, this is awkward. Thank you for pointing it out. Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

In your loop you update `int_index` but not `indexer`. So every loop iteration uses the same `indexer` value and overwrites the same entry in the `dict`, so you only have one value that gets preserved.